# Team Foundation Server - Committed files appear hidden for other TFS-Members

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, tfs, visual-studio-2012

Since some months, we are using TFS 2012 with Visual Studio 2012 and until some weeks we didn't notice any problems during checking in/out. Furthermore, we are working on a ASP.NET MVC4 project. 
But recently, we noticed that if Person A checks in new files (f.i. .cs or .cshtml) and Person B does "Get latest version", then he receives those files but they are hidden for some reason. So we have to do "Include in project" manually every time. This happens to any of us. 
Neither I have direct access to the TFS configuration nor did I change my Visual Studio settings. Thus, it is really strange that this happens for no known reason.

Do you have any ideas what I should try or check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only time I have seen this kind of behavior is when someone checks in the files, but not the corresponding `.csproj` file.  The .csproj file contains the definition of what files are included, so for the solution to build with the new files, the .csproj file must be checked in as well.

Note that it may be necessary on occasion to do a "Save All" before the changes to the .csproj file are committed.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick :) everybody had his own .csproj file because it was exluded by somebody but now I added it again to source control.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend checking the `.csproj` file of the last few check-ins that have had this problem. I've encountered this any number of times when one of my co-workers "Excludes this file" from the project because they don't understand why something isn't working. They forget to re-include it in the project and then check everything back in. The project file doesn't contain the files that were excluded.